# How to manually create a DBRef using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, dbref

I want to create a DBRef manually so that I can add an additional field to it.  However, when I try to pass the following:

```
{'$ref': 'projects', '$id': '1029412409721', 'project_name': 'My Project'}
```

Pymongo raises an error:

```
pymongo.errors.InvalidName: key '$id' must not start with '$'
```

It would seem that pymongo reserve the `$` for the special key, leading me to wonder if it is even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably don't want to be creating them manually like that, since keys in DBRefs need to be ordered. We could add an option to create a DBRef instance w/ custom kwargs though, which would solve your problem. If you file a jira for this we should be able to get it out in an upcoming release.

Comment: Yeah, I used the dict syntax for brevity here.  I originally used a SON object which, as far as I can tell, maintains key order.  However, the keys still refused to let me use $.

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe we should special case for DBRef to let you create manually, but I think your JIRA case is a better solution. Will try to get that out soon.

Comment: The restriction on $ starting a key makes sense, but is probably unnecessary.  Perhaps raising a warning rather than an exception, or simply documenting the fact that $ keys are reserved would suffice?

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is now sone through `bson.dbref.DBRef`.